# Swift 3 viewWillTransitionToSize not being called

Tags: swift

I have this method in my swift 3 code:

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

Why isn't viewWillTransitionToSize being called?

Comment: __1.__ when would you like that method to get called? __2.__ why do you think the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key in your `.plist` file has anything to do with that? please, be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On migration process from swift2.x to Swift3 'viewWillTransition' method has changed:

**Swift2.x**

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

**Swift3**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

Changing the key *withTransitionCoordinator* to *with*